# Sort multiple React Table instances simultaneously

Tags: reactjs, sorting, react-table, react-table-v7

I'm new to React and I'm trying to sort two React Table instances simultaneously. I have searched all over the place, but I haven't found anything about it so far.

Simplified scenario for the setup. Both tables have the same columns but different data. If I sort for example 'total' in left table, how can I sort the same column in right table at the same time?

```
function App() {
...

return (
  <div>
    <div className="left-table">
      <Table columns={columns} data={data1} />
    </div>
    <div className="right-table">
      <Table columns={columns} data={data2} />
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
```

**EDIT**

For now it seems that the best way to achieve what I want, is to create buttons/checkboxes that determine which columns need to be sorted and pass that info to the table component(s) and use setSortBy there.